# CSV file uploader - check cell content and process action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, csv-import

CSV file has a header called account_id.
The content of this cell is either an 8 digit account number or a 12 digit account number.

If 8 digit, process method A.
If 12 digit, process method B.

Does someone know how do write the write code for that. I'm using 'csv' from rails.

Thank you

Comment: The code for what part of this? And what have you tried so far to solve it?

Comment: are you importing from cssv or exporting to csv?